# If F is a diffeomorphism and $F_*$ preserves dot products, then F is an isometry.

Tags: differential-geometry

Exercise from O'neill's book *ELEMENTARY DIFFERENTIAL GEOMETRY* (p.121)

**$If \quad F:R^3\to R^3\quad is \quad a\quad diffeomorphism\quad such \quad that \quad (its\quad  tangent\quad map)\quad  F_*\quad preserves \quad dot\quad products,\quad show\quad that\quad F\quad is \quad an\quad isometry. \quad HINT:\quad Show\quad that\quad F\quad preserves\quad lengths\quad of\quad curve\quad segments\quad and\quad deduce\quad that\quad F^{-1}\quad does\quad also.$**

It seems a simple problem, but I can't come up with an idea. How can we derive a property of an original map from a property of its tangent map? Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x,y\in \mathbb R^3$ and $\gamma$ any curve connecting them. You want to show that $\ell(f(\gamma))=\ell(\gamma)$ then since the metric is given by the following: $d(x,y)=\inf \ell(\gamma)$ or $\gamma$ connecting $x$ to $y$ you get the result (you need to do it for the inverse as well, but that is just noting that if $f$ is a diffeomorphism all such paths from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$ arise as $f(\gamma)$ for some path from $x$ to $y$).

Comment: Thank you very much. So the hypothesis that $F_*$ preserves dot products is used to prove $||F(\gamma)||=||\gamma||$?

Comment: yes then you use the diffeomorphism to say that the family of curves is the same

Comment: Thanks so much. That helps a lot :)